# Do I need induction to prove this?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Show that if $B_1, B_2, \ldots , B_n \subseteq T,$ then $$f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \cdots \cap B_n) = f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2) \cap \cdots \cap f^{-1}(B_n).$$

**My question is:**

I got a hint to use induction to prove this in which I should prove the base case for $n=2,$ but my opinion is I do not need induction and I will just prove this by the same way I proved the statement for the case $n = 2.$ Could anyone tell me which is the correct idea please?

Comment: You can do without the induction. It should be noted, however, that a lot of "obvious" things involve, when you look close enough, an inductive argument.

Comment: Do you mean that I can prove it by exactly the same way I prove the statement when $n=2$? @Reveillark

Comment: what inductive argument is included here? @Reveillark

Comment: I assume your strategy is saying $x\in f^{-1}(B_1\cap \dots \cap B_n)\iff f(x)\in B_1\cap \dots \cap B_n \iff \forall i\in \{1,\dots,n\}f(x)\in B_i \iff \forall i\in \{1,\dots,n\} x\in f^{-1}(B_i)\iff x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(B_i)$. That would work. I might've spoken too quickly, and you can do without the induction here.

Comment: I actually tried to use the ordinary induction but I did not know how to use the induction hypothesis @Reveillark

Comment: yes exactly this is my strategy @Reveillark

Comment: If you did want to prove it by induction, argue that $f^{-1}(B_1\cap \dots \cap B_n)=f^{-1}(B_1\cap \dots B_{n-1} \cap B_n )=f^{-1}(B_1\cap \dots \cap B_{n-1})\cap f^{-1}(B_n)$ by the $n=2$ case. Can you see how to continue?

Comment: No, I can not @Reveillark

Comment: From where I left off, $f^{-1}(B_1\cap\dots \cap B_{n-1})=f^{-1}(B_1)\cap\dots\cap f^{-1}(B_{n-1})$ by the inductive hypothesis

Comment: I think using induction makes it more complicated.am I correct? Could you show me the details of proving it by induction (assuming that I know how to prove it in case of  $n=2$)

Comment: Also, how can I argue the claim you mentioned in your comment just before last?

Comment: Induction only makes rigorous what exactly we mean by arbitrary $n$. But, in most mathematical proofs not dealing with the technicalities of peano axioms, one can generally assume the arbitrariness of the integer n and just presume we can, indeed, reason about operations of '$n$ amount'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use induction here.
\begin{align}
& w \in f^{-1} \left( B_1\cap \cdots \cap B_n \right) \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & f(w) \in B_1\cap \cdots \cap B_n \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\,\, f(w)\in B_i \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\,\, w\in f^{-1}(B_i) \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & w \in f^{-1}(B_1) \cap \cdots \cap f^{-1}(B_n).
\end{align}

In fact,
$$
f^{-1} \left( \bigcap_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I} B_i \right) = \bigcap_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I} f^{-1}(B_i),
$$
with no assumption that $\mathcal I$ is finite.

Proof:
\begin{align}
& w \in f^{-1} \left( \bigcap_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I} B_i \right) \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & f(w) \in \bigcap_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I} B_i \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & \text{ for all } i\in\mathcal I,\,\, f(w)\in B_i \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & \text{ for all } i\in\mathcal I,\,\, w\in f^{-1}(B_i) \\[8pt]
\text{iff } & w \in \bigcap_{i\,\in\,\mathcal I} f^{-1}(B_i).
\end{align}

Comment: Can $I$ be uncountable? is the induction can be used for infinite sets (just a general question)?

Comment: $\mathcal I$ can be uncountable. No assumptions about the cardinality of $\mathbb I $ are involved. No use is made of induction.

Answer (score 1):

No, induction is not needed nor does the number of B's have to be finite.
Let C be a collection of sets.
Theorem.
f$^{-1}$($\cap$C) = $\cap${ f$^{-1}$(B) : B in C }.
Proof.
x in f$^{-1}$($\cap$C) iff
f(x) in $\cap$C iff
for all B in C, f(x) in B iff
for all B in C, x in f$^{-1}$(B) iff
x in $\cap${ f$^{-1}$(B) : B in C }.

Exercise.  Prove, in a similar fashion,
f$^{-1}$($\cup$C) = $\cup${ f$^{-1}$(B) : B in C }.

Comment: You persist in not using MathJax/Latex, why is that? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and the links there.